# Cocoa - Loaded nib file disappears when focus is lost

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib

I have a nib file I've loaded like so `[NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"myNibFile" owner: self ]` and it pops up fine, but when it loses focus, it simply disappears. I've checked to see if it's vanishing behind my main window but it's not. My app is pretty big so I'm not sure what could be causing it. I have garbage collection enabled if that makes any difference. Does anyone know of any problems with loaded nib files and losing focus that I should look into? If necessary I can start posting some samples from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... I just deleted the nib I was loading and recreated it and it started working. Strange... Seems fixed now though.